# Can't set attrs in IntegerField() widget in model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to make a form in Django using model forms but i am facing a problem. Following is my code in forms.py which has an `IntegerField()`, I want to set a custom id and class for it but I'm not able to do so with the help of `attrs` in widget of `IntegerField()` whereas for `CharField()` it works.

**`forms.CharField(widget=forms.CharField(attrs={'id': 'customID'}))` works** but

**`hours = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.IntegerField(attrs={'id': 'blah', }))` doesn't**.

**forms.py**

```
class TimerForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    hours = forms.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=0, widget=forms.IntegerField(attrs={'id': 'blah', }))        

    class Meta:
        model = Timer
        fields = ['hours']
```

**Error in cmd:**

> super(IntegerField, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>  TypeError:
>   **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Comment: Neither of these would work. Neither IntegerField nor CharField are widgets; they are fields, hence the names.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay thanks for pointing that out, i'm new to Django. Could you suggest a way to do what i want? Is there a native way to set custom attributes of input fields or must custom fields be made in order to do what i want to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use fields there. You should use the relevant [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/): TextInput and NumberInput.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped!

Answer (score 5):

You should do something like that:

```
class TimerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Timer
       fields=['hours']
       widgets = {
           'hours': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min': '0', 'class': 'yourClass', 'id': 'blah'}),
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
org_mobile_no = forms.IntegerField(required=True, label="Mobile No",
                                   widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'number',
                                                                   'id': 'org_mobile_no',
                                                                   'name': 'org_mobile_no',
                                                                   'value': "",
                                                                   'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Either you can set id or name and value, if you want to use name and id for javascript do it, it will work.

I know am late but i answered beacuse i wasted my lots of time. So i wanna help.